# SQL query issue with zero discount

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using the below query to get total amount after a discount.

My issue is when the discount is equal to zero, the total amount becomes zero.

How can I resolve this issue?

```
SELECT  
    CAST(SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice * (Discount / 100)) AS varchar(50))  
FROM
    Stock_Purchase_Details
```

Comment: `0` multiplied by any number will result `0`. What are you expecting

Comment: Your Discount might be "off from 100 pct"   So your logic might need to use  (1 - (Discount/100))     0 meaning zero percent off  .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple case construct

```
unitPrice * 
case when discount > 0 then (discount / 100)
else 1 end
```

That's for the code you posted.  Normally, a discounted price is

```
unitPrice * ((100 - discount) / 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want final amount after discount, you should use

```
CAST(SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice * (1-(Discount/100)) AS VARCHAR(50))
```

This will give you the amount after discount. Your current formula gives you the amount discounted, not the amount after discount

Answer (score 0):

Why not check to see if Discount/0 is 0 before doing that, and if it is zero, then don't include it? This can be done via case statements:

```
CASE 
     WHEN (Discount/100) = 0 then (logic)
     ELSE (other logic)
END
```

Just one solution, as I am sure there are others.

Answer (score 0):

Just by looking at your query, Discount means percentage discounted, not percent discount. In other words, per your SQL query, if Discount is 60%, it doesn't mean 60% off, but it's 40% off.

I'm assuming that's not what you want, so the correct query should be:

```
SELECT  Cast(SUM(Quantity * UnitPrice * ((100-Discount)/100)) as varchar(50))
from Stock_Purchase_Details
```